# Why did Shrek’s human form have hair?

Tags: shrek

In Shrek 2, Shrek and Donkey drink the Happily Ever After Potion, which turns Shrek human.

But when he turns human, he has hair. Why, when he didn’t have hair when he was an ogre?

And in case anyone says that “apparently, having hair is beautiful,” bald people CAN be beautiful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shrek as a franchise, right from the book, is about playing with conventional standards of conformity and subverting them.

The Happily Ever After Potion™ is designed with the same conventional standards in mind as Prince Charming and all of the Fairy Godmother's offerings. Ergo, it did its level best to make Shrek into the most conventionally attractive human being that any princess could hope to marry. And, given the character of the Fairy Godmother being who she is/was, that means beautiful, flowing locks. Just be grateful they weren't golden.

As a bald man, I do appreciate your last sentence. And donkeys can be beautiful too.

Comment: And on the news, there is a bald little girl dressed up as her favourite Disney Princesses, the message is that “Bald is beautiful,” which I agree with. https://www.huffingtonpost.ca/entry/disney-princess-photoshoot_ca_5f973e9fc5b6b74d85f3a6f1